# Golang (iris webframework) share between handlers

Tags: go

I am currently using the iris web framework and since questions cannot be asked on the issue tracker and the community chat is dead I am asking this here hoping someone helps me out.

I need to pass data to the c.Render function

I have a handler that checks if the user is logged or not. If its not logged I should add an extra button to the html page

```
iris.Use(userHandler{})

type userHandler struct{
    Allow bool
}

func (u userHandler) Serve(c *iris.Context) {
    ...
    if isLogged {
        // When I call from another middleware (c.Next) c.Render it should know that the user is logged in
    }
    c.Next()
}
```

So is it possible to add some default data to the c.Render function?

Comment: Can you use https://github.com/kataras/iris/blob/master/context.go#L820 ?

Answer (score 2):

```
// retrieve local storage or previous handler,
// this is how handlers can share values, with the context's Values().
logged := ctx.Values().Get("logged")

// set template data {{.isLogged}}
ctx.ViewData("isLogged", logged)

// and finally, render the mypage.html
ctx.View("mypage.html")
```

`"logged"` can be set to your middleware/any previous handler by:

`ctx.Values().Set("logged", false)`

All these are described to the examples, you're welcome to explore some of those there: https://github.com/kataras/iris/tree/master/_examples

Happy Coding!